# Selenium Webdriver Automatic Redirecting

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

**Problem Description:**

I am currently trying to set up a Selenium webdriver in Java. 
However every time I try to load this specific webpage: [Expected Website](https://www.liketoknow.it/featured) I end up with this [Unintentional Website](https://www.liketoknow.it). No matter which driver I use (Firefox,Chrome,Edge), I somehow always get redirected and I did not find any solution to overcome this. Please note that the page loads some JS during the page loading process. This might be causing this redirection.

However if I use a standard browser I get the Expected Website as wished.

**Goal:**

Load this website with a Selenium webdriver: [Expected Website](https://www.liketoknow.it/featured)

**Additional Information:**

The code I am using so far:

```
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:/Downloads/geckodriver.exe");
     File pathToBinary = new File(
     "C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla   Firefox/firefox.exe");

     FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
     FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
     driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,firefoxProfile);

     driver.get("https://www.liketoknow.it/featured");
        try {
             Thread.sleep(10000);
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {}

     driver.quit();
```

Comment: IDK i get redirected to https://www.liketoknow.it/ no matter which link I click on normal web browser.

Comment: wierd. i dont. I noticed that on my phone i also get redirected. so apparently the "mobile" user gets redirected. and selenium, the way I set it up, seems to appear as a mobile user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens is the following:

If you want to open this page you have to have granted access. To have so you have to first login on the main webpage.

For other people having a similar issues of getting redirected:

Use a different user agent when you set up your Webdriver and switch to a either mobile or PC/MAC, depending on your needs.

Cheers

Answer (score -2):

Have you seen that /featured is redirecting to the root site literally?

I would go for that first. Probably is something related with it and you will end with the same result if you connect to https://www.liketoknow.it/ in the first place.

Comment: for such generic comments please use comment versus answer.  

This is not an answer to question, but more a tell me more.

Comment: I know it's generic but considering the Selenium "world" fail and try, this is not so generic. You have to consider that, at the end, its a browser automation testing framework, so this response, I would say, does not go out of scope for being an acceptable answer.

Comment: The thing is that I do not get redirected if I use a standard browser. Isnt that wierd?

Comment: What do you mean by standard browser? I've tried it with Firefox and Chrome and so far both do the redirecting.

Comment: If you simply open the link in a normal webbrowser then you dont get redirected. But if you use selenium webdrivers you get redirected. Correct?